# how to convert long raw data type to readable format(oracle version :11.2.0.3.0) in oracle?

Tags: oracle, long-integer, varchar2, readable

how to convert long raw data type to readable format(oracle version :11.2.0.3.0)  in oracle?

Please help me
oracle version :11.2.0.3.0
i want to convert long raw data type to readable format

Answer (score 1):

I use [this code](https://github.com/oracle-developer/dla) from Adrian Billington.  It has versions that work on Oracle 9, 10 and 11 and probably 12.

Essentially the code reads the LONG data and converts it on the fly into a CLOB. You can expose this as a view or select from TABLE(function call)

Comment: That code works with LONG data types, but not LONG RAW.

Answer (score 1):

For analyzing LONG value from system views I use PL/SQL. As example:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR curs IS
    SELECT p.high_value -- LONG value
          ,p.table_name
          ,p.partition_name
    FROM user_tab_partitions p;
  c         curs%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN curs 
    LOOP
      IF c.high_value like '%CD_FEED%'
        THEN dbms_output.put_line(c.table_name);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: That will not work with LONG RAW data types.